# New IIS site on Windows Server 2016 always returns 404 Not Found

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I am setting up a server with Windows Server 2016 for the first time, and when creating a new IIS website, I am finding that all requests return 404 Not Found.

Looking through the web server logs, there are no requests being logged. Looking at the HTTPERR log, I can see NotFound errors being logged, but the documentation that I have looked at (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820729/error-logging-in-http-apis) doesn't list NotFound as a supported error reason.

The app is a vanilla ASP.NET MVC application based on .NET Framework 4.6.2; I have tried placing an empty index.html in the application root folder and setting it as the default document, but that doesn't work either.

Here's a typical line from the logs:

```
2018-03-26 00:39:19 192.168.3.252 60475 192.168.3.11 443 HTTP/0.9 GET / - 404 - NotFound -
```

Two things are puzzling me from that log entry - why does it give the HTTP version as 0.9 instead of 1.1 or 2.0 as I would expect, and why does give the path as / instead of e.g.  `/index.html`  or `/home/index` as I would expect?

Comment: Try to access the web site locally on the IIS server first. Only if it works locally you can try to access it from other machines.

Answer (score 1):

The logged path is always the one from the actual HTTP request, never a resulting path i.e. HTTP path after the rewrite or real filesystem path. This part of your log line is completely normal.

> *CookedURL + Query*
>
> The URL and any query that is associated with it are logged as one
>   field that is separated by a question mark (`0x3F`). This field is
>   truncated at its length limit of 4,096 bytes.

The `HTTP/0.9` is just a result of a (either malformed or ancient) very simple `GET /` request without the `HTTP/version` part and additional request lines: the [HTTP 0.9](https://hpbn.co/brief-history-of-http/#http-09-the-one-line-protocol) was a one-liner protocol without any headers, including the `Host:` introduced in the HTTP 1.1 standard. The lack of `Host:` header means that the *Default Web Site* gets used instead of the *binding* your actual site has. If the default web site doesn't have index, the `404 - Not found` may have been caused by that.

From the details in your question alone I can't deduce what could be causing such queries. Could there be something between the browser and the IIS?

Comment: Just the usual firewall/load balancer.

Comment: There is no URL rewriting going on in the application; even if I change the website to just point to a folder containing a single index.html, it still gives the same `/` path. Sounds like I need another talk with our hosting provider to see where this old protocol is coming from.

Comment: @DavidKeaveny I would check with them, as in 0.9 even chunked encoding is not supported, which in turn block you for like more multimedia from your website (like flash) or upload or such, just to cite some example

Answer (score 0):

From the log entry you posted, it looks like you are connecting directly to the server from a client machine in the same network. Are you trying to connect to the website by IP address or DNS name?

It sounds like you have a host name configured and are trying to access the website by IP address. How do you have your binding configured?